# validate date : python

Tags: python, validation, date

I want to know how to convert different format dates to expected format in python .

ex : i want to get this format : 2/29/2012

['2012-02-01 // 2012-02-28', '2/15/2012', '2/13/2012', '2/14/2012', '2/23/2012', '2/18/2012', '2/29/2012']

How to check today date in the range '2012-02-01 // 2012-02-28'

Share your suggestions

Comment: What is your input? What is your desired output? What did you try?

Comment: Like ex My i/p : ['2012-02-01 // 2012-02-28', '2/15/2012', '2/13/2012', 'mar/14/2012', '2/23/2012', '2/feb/2012', '2012/2/22'] My expected o/p : 2/23/2012

Answer (score 0):

Use the datetime library in python. You can just compare two different datetime.datetime objects. And you can separate the year, month, date thing to put it in anyform you want.

Check this link for all the library details.
http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The [dateutil](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) python library parses a wider variety of date formats than the standard datetime module.